# resize partition overlapping parted

Tags: linux, centos, fdisk, parted, resize2fs

**parted -s -a opt /dev/sda "print free"**

```
Modèle: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disque /dev/sda : 268GB
Taille des secteurs (logiques/physiques): 512B/512B
Table de partitions : gpt
Disk Flags:

Numéro  Début   Fin     Taille  Système de fichiers  Nom                   Fanions
        17,4kB  1049kB  1031kB  Espace libre
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32                EFI System Partition  démarrage, esp
 2      538MB   1075MB  537MB   ext4
 3      1075MB  20,4GB  19,3GB                                             lvm (gestionnaire de volumes logiques)
        20,4GB  20,4GB  16,9kB  Espace libre
 4      20,4GB  106GB   85,9GB                                             lvm (gestionnaire de volumes logiques)
 5      106GB   133GB   26,8GB                                             lvm (gestionnaire de volumes logiques)
 6      133GB   140GB   6442MB                                             lvm (gestionnaire de volumes logiques)
 7      140GB   162GB   22,4GB                                             lvm (gestionnaire de volumes logiques)
        162GB   268GB   106GB   Espace libre
```

I just don't understand why i got this line : 20,4GB  20,4GB  16,9kB  Espace libre (free space)

**parted -s -a opt /dev/sda "resizepart 3 100%"**

```
Erreur: Impossible d'avoir des partitions qui se chevauchent.
```

This means : *Unable to have overlapping partitions*

Any idea on what can i do to finaly have a success on my resizepart ?

Comment: You cannot add space to existing partition/lvm due to the fact that the Free space is too small and doesn't match what was called Cylinders/Block on HDD. But in this case you are able to create one Volume Group that can handle several Logical volume. In this case you will have one VG with several LV's without any Free space in the middle.

Comment: there's no way to kick out the free space in the middle to only keep the good free space at the end ?

Comment: for parted, `100%` means you are trying to resize the partition to the end of disk. that doesn't work since you have other partitions in the way. try `unit s print free` to get the specific sector offset you can resize to.

Comment: Thanks @frostschutz, i got the two lines result : `39845855s   39845887s   33s  Free Space` and the good one `316406251s  524287966s 207881716s  Free Space` 

How can i indicate the resize with the specific sector ?

Comment: `resizepart 3 39845887s`

Comment: it worked, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The answer which work from Frostschutz :

> for parted, 100% means you are trying to resize the partition to the
> end of disk. that doesn't work since you have other partitions in the
> way. try unit s print free to get the specific sector offset you can
> resize to